# Hibernate - One table with multiple entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, blob

I have a `Picture`:

```
public class Picture implements java.io.Serializable {

    private byte[] picEncoded;
    private String Name;
    //etc
```

Is it's possible to move `byte[]` to another class without creating physically separated table in db? Do i need to use some inheritance strategy?

**edit**

Blob in separate entity:

**pojo**:

```
 public class PictureBlob implements java.io.Serializable {
        private Integer pictureBlobId;
        private byte[] blob;
```

**hbm:**:

```
<class name="PictureBlob" table="PICTURE">

<id name="pictureBlobId" type="int">
  <column length="200" name="PictureID"/>      
</id>

<property name="blob" type="byte[]" insert="false" update="false">
  <column name="PicEncoded" not-null="false"/>
</property>
</class>
```

Picture:

**hbm:**:

```
  <one-to-one class="PictureBlob" constrained="true" name="pictureBlob" fetch="select"/>
```

How do i insert new pictures?

```
PictureBlob pictureBlob= new PictureBlob();
        pictureBlob.setBlob(new byte[]{84,32,22});
        Picture p = new Picture();
        p.setPictureBlob(pictureBlob);           
        session.save(p);
```

inserts record where blob value is null.

Comment: sqlite doesnt have a blob type. you can cut out the type attribute. hibernate will figure it out

Comment: removed type="byte[]". nothing changed.

Comment: have you disabled lazyloading for Picture class?

Comment: no. Associations to other entities load lazy as usual.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it's possible to move byte[] to another class without creating
>   physically separated table in db?

Use component mapping which creates a composition relation between Picture and PictureBlob. Example:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Picture" table="PICTURE">
  <id name="pictureId" type="int">
   <generator class="native" />
  </id>
 <component name="pictureBlob " class="PictureBlob" lazy="no-proxy">
  <property name="pictureBlobId" column="PictureID" type="int" length="200" />
  <property name="blob" type="byte[]" insert="false" update="false"column="PicEncoded"/>
 </component>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

POJO

```
public class Picture implements java.io.Serializable {
 private int pictureId;
 private PictureBlob pictureBlob;

 //Setters & Getters
}

public class PictureBlob implements java.io.Serializable {
 private int pictureBlobId;
 private byte[] blob;

 //Setters & Getters
}
```

Also Note:

> Use `lazy="true"` on , and  mappings to enable lazy
>   loading of individual scalar value-typed properties (a somewhat exotic
>   case). Requires bytecode instrumentation of compiled persistent
>   classes for the injection of interception code. Can be overriden in
>   HQL with FETCH ALL PROPERTIES.
>
> Use `lazy="no-proxy"` on single-valued associations to enable lazy
>   fetching without the use of a proxy. Requires bytecode instrumentation
>   for the injection of interception code.
>
> Use `lazy="extra"` on collections for "smart" collection behavior, i.e.
>   some collection operations such as `size(), contains(), get(),` etc. do
>   not trigger collection initialization. This is only sensible for very
>   large collections.

[See here for more info. on fetching strategies](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies?_sscc=t)

**Edited.**

Answer (score 3):

if you interested in using annotations instead of hbm you can take a look at these

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html, this will exactly solve  your purpose.

Comment: do i need byte code enhancements to make embedded objects lazy loaded?

Comment: you dont need byte code enhancements i guess....there is one more annotation Basic for which we can specify the fetch type. this link has extensive details about Embedded, Embeddable and Basic annotations. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html You can try combining those and you achieve what you are thinking...

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use something like this:

```
<class name="Picture">
    <id name="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name"/>

    <component name="pictureBlob" class="PictureBlob">
       <property name="pictureBlobId"/>
       <property name="blob"/>
       <property name="picture"/>
    </component>
</class>
```

This might need some edititng, but the idea is this:
You have a `Picture` class. This class has property `name` and property `pictureBlob` of type `PictureBlob`.

the `component` tag indicates the properties inside the component are mapped to the same table as `Picture`

Comment: Thanks for answer! This works but pictureBlob is not lazy loaded (even with 'lazy="true"' in component tag).